# jQuery UI 1.11.1 - dynamic dialog positioning not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

With jQuery UI 1.10.4 its working fine, but with jQuery UI 1.11.1 it´s not working.

Dialog positioning with jQuery UI:

http://jsfiddle.net/avpbsnx3/

```
# working with 1.10.4

$(document).on('click', '.recenter', function () {
    $('#myDialog').dialog("option", "position", { my: 'center', at: 'center' });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6kkn9oqj/

```
# not working with 1.11.1

$(document).on('click', '.recenter', function () {
    $('#myDialog').dialog("option", "position", { my: 'center', at: 'center' });
});
```

Is this a bug in the new version, or am I using it wrong?

**Edit:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.recenter', function () {
    $('#myDialog').dialog("option", "position", { my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window });
});
```

It seems that there is a default-reference problem. Its working fine with the code above.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that some "unofficial" values for position that used to work now no longer work.  There are lots of examples on the net of using position: "center", for example, and this works on 1.10.4 (whether it works because it actually works or is being ignored and using the default).  The documentation states that the default is position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window }.  It seems that specifying "center" or an incomplete definition now defaults to top left positioning when used during creation of the dialog, or is ignored when attempting to reposition.

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position